# Recursive query in Mysql

Tags: mysql

Hi i have a table in MySql with 2 columns : empId and mId. empId is the code of an employee and mId the code of his manager. 
I need to query all the reportees of a manager ie direct and indirect reportee.

I saw some links on google but they don't seem to work. Can somebody help me regarding this.

Example : 
Sample hierarchy tree looks like

```
1
 (2       3      )
   (4    5) (6 7)
     (8 9)
```

Hence when queried for 1 the query should return all the nodes in the tree except for 1 and when queries for 2 it should return 4 5 8 9.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

This is the link that i tried
http://guilhembichot.blogspot.co.uk/2013/11/with-recursive-and-mysql.html
This link explains how to create a recursive query but the methods explained over here don't seem to work for me.

@Mike Brant : I check out the link in your comment. But that link was not of much use as i would have to alter the schema of my table to incorporate Nested State Model.And for the first approach i guess i need to know the depth of the tree i am querying for whereas in my problem the depth is unknown.

The schema for my table is:
create table employees
{

```
 empId int not null, 
 mId int, 
 primary key (empId)
```

};

Comment: Hello! Please post a real schema of your tables! as well as the mysql you have tried to do this. Right now your question does not show that much research effort. protip: when I read things like `I saw some links on google but they don't seem to work` I almost instantly think the contrary. show us those links, before claiming you've tried things

Comment: So it seems you already have a good idea of implementing a nested set tree hierarchy in MySQL.  With that approach, there is no need for recursive querying.  It is not clear to me what problem you are actually having as you are not showing your actual table data and queries.

Comment: Here is an excellent article on managing trees in different ways in relational databases.  http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/